# Theorem about equivalent norms.

Tags: field-theory

Let $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ be equivalent norms on a [normed field](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Norm_on_a_field). Then

(i) $\|x\|_1<1$ iff $\|x\|_2<1$; $\|x\|_1>1$ iff $\|x\|_2>1;$

(ii) $\|x\|=1$ iff $\|x\|_2=1$.

I want to prove this using the following definition,

Two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are equivalent if there exists $a,b>0$ such that $a\|\cdot\|_1\leq \|\cdot\|_2\leq b\|\cdot\|_1$. It is equivalent to saying that $1/a\|\cdot\|_2\leq \|\cdot\|_1\leq 1/b\|\cdot\|_2$.

Suppose $\|x\|_2<1$.  Then $\|x\|_1< 1/b$. It is need not be true that $1/b<1$. Please help me!

Comment: I believe there are some restrictions for this result, since otherwise pick $a:=b:=1/2$, so that $\|x\|_1=2\|x\|_2$, which provides a counterexample at least for (ii). What kind of space is the space on which the norms are defined?

Comment: This can't be true. Just compare the equivalent norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ on the point $(1,1)$.

Comment: The only way this is true is if the norms are identical. Either one of the two conditions implies that.

Comment: yes, these are the norms on a normed field.

Comment: Note that this is about a normed field. The norms have to be also multiplicative in addition to the other standard properties.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Definition_for_normed_fields

Comment: It would probably good to clarify in your post what is a *normed field*. (I have added a link - you should check whether definition in that link is the same as you are using.)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$||x||_1 < 1 \iff ||x||_1^n \to 0 \iff  ||x^n||_1 \to 0 
\iff ||x^n||_2 \to 0 \iff ||x||_2^n \to 0 \iff ||x||_2 <1$$

Obs: Note that both norms are multiplicative, that is

$$||x^n||= ||x||^n$$

Comment: @orangeskid this threw me at first, of course I'm used to Functional Analysis and normed *vector spaces*. I recall this to be a more *algebraic* sort of norm.

Comment: @DanZimm: Yes, it is more algebraic. It shows up with more often with $p$-adic  fields and their extensions. Indeed, you would expect it to be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, like it's usual for a normed vector space.

Comment: @orangeskid I see :) I also more used to normed spaces, know a little bit about Banach algebras, which submultiplicative norms.

Comment: @daw: An example of a norm on $\mathbb{Q}$ that is not the usual one is : $|r|_2 = 2^{-a}$ if $2^a$ is the exponent of $2$ in the decomposition of $r$ ( and $|0|_2=0$). For instance,  $|\frac{24}{35}|_2= 2^{-3}= \frac{1}{8}$. And you can do this for any prime $p$ and get a norm $|\cdot |_p$ (called a $p$-adic norm). At some point the real and the $p$-adic norms would interact.

Comment: @orangeskid just curious, would $\left\lvert \frac{1}{24} \right\rvert_2 = 2^3 = 8$?

Comment: @DanZimm: Correct. Note also that $|\frac{1}{24}|_3= 3^1 = 3$ and $|\frac{1}{24}|_p=1$ for all other primes $p$.